# How do I solve this ambiguous type variable error in Haskell?

Tags: variables, haskell, typeerror, huffman-code, ambiguous

I couldn't find an answer to my question among several ambiguous type variable error questions. 
I'm currently trying to get this code I found to work. (https://gist.github.com/kirelagin/3886243)

My code:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Function

main = do
    putStrLn "Start test"
    let foo = "Hello World"
    let freqTest = freqList foo
    putStrLn "Frequentie list"
    print freqTest
    putStrLn "Done.."
    let treeTest = buildTree freqTest
    putStrLn "Huffman Tree"
    print treeTest
    putStrLn "Done.."
    let codeMaphTest = buildCodemap treeTest
    putStrLn "Codemap ding"
    -- print codeMaphTest
    putStrLn "Done.."




--This typeclass is supposed to make life _a bit_ easier.

class Eq a => Bits a where
    zer :: a
    one :: a

instance Bits Int where
    zer = 0
    one = 1

instance Bits Bool where
    zer = False
    one = True

-- Codemap is generated from a Huffman tree. It is used for fast encoding.

type Codemap a = M.Map Char [a]

-- Huffman tree is a simple binary tree. Each leaf contains a Char and its weight.
-- Fork (node with children) also has weight = sum of weights of its children.

data HTree  = Leaf Char Int
            | Fork HTree HTree Int
            deriving (Show)

weight :: HTree -> Int
weight (Leaf _ w)    = w
weight (Fork _ _ w)  = w

-- The only useful operation on Huffman trees is merging, that is we take
-- two trees and make them children of a new Fork-node.

merge t1 t2 = Fork t1 t2 (weight t1 + weight t2)

-- `freqList` is an utility function. It takes a string and produces a list
-- of pairs (character, number of occurences of this character in the string).

freqList :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
freqList = M.toList . M.fromListWith (+) . map (flip (,) 1)

-- `buildTree` builds a Huffman tree from a list of character frequencies
-- (obtained, for example, from `freqList` or elsewhere).
-- It sorts the list in ascending order by frequency, turns each (char, freq) pair
-- into a one-leaf tree and keeps merging two trees with the smallest frequencies
-- until only one tree is remaining.

buildTree :: [(Char, Int)] -> HTree
buildTree = bld . map (uncurry Leaf) . sortBy (compare `on` snd)
    where   bld (t:[]) = t
            bld (a:b:cs) = bld $ insertBy (compare `on` weight) (merge a b) cs

-- The next function traverses a Huffman tree to obtain a list of codes for
-- all characters and converts this list into a `Map`.

buildCodemap :: Bits a => HTree -> Codemap a
buildCodemap = M.fromList . buildCodelist
    where   buildCodelist (Leaf c w) = [(c, [])]
            buildCodelist (Fork l r w) = map (addBit zer) (buildCodelist l) ++ map (addBit one) (buildCodelist r)
                where addBit b = second (b :)

-- Simple functions to get a Huffman tree or a `Codemap` from a `String`.

stringTree :: String -> HTree
stringTree = buildTree . freqList

stringCodemap :: Bits a => String -> Codemap a
stringCodemap = buildCodemap . stringTree

-- Time to do the real encoding and decoding!

-- Encoding function just represents each character of a string by corresponding
-- sequence of `Bit`s.

encode :: Bits a => Codemap a -> String -> [a]
encode m = concat . map (m M.!)

encode' :: Bits a => HTree -> String -> [a]
encode' t = encode $ buildCodemap t

-- Decoding is a little trickier. We have to traverse the tree until
-- we reach a leaf which means we've just finished reading a sequence
-- of `Bit`s corresponding to a single character.
-- We keep doing this to process the whole list of `Bit`s.

decode :: Bits a => HTree -> [a] -> String
decode tree = dcd tree
    where   dcd (Leaf c _) [] = [c]
            dcd (Leaf c _) bs = c : dcd tree bs
            dcd (Fork l r _) (b:bs) = dcd (if b == zer then l else r) bs
```

**Output:**

```
huffmancompress.hs:17:24: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `buildCodemap'
      prevents the constraint `(Bits a0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        codeMaphTest :: Codemap a0 (bound at huffmancompress.hs:17:9)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Bits Bool -- Defined at huffmancompress.hs:35:10
        instance Bits Int -- Defined at huffmancompress.hs:31:10
    * In the expression: buildCodemap treeTest
      In an equation for `codeMaphTest':
          codeMaphTest = buildCodemap treeTest
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "Start test"
           let foo = "Hello World"
           let freqTest = freqList foo
           putStrLn "Frequentie list"
           ....
   |
17 |     let codeMaphTest = buildCodemap treeTest
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried serveral things I found on the internet but nothing worth mentioning to be honest.

Maybe any of you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 3):

On line 17, where the error points you:

```
let codeMaphTest = buildCodemap treeTest
```

What type is `codeMaphTest`? Should it be `Codemap Int`? Or `Codemap String`? Or, perhaps, `Codemap Bool`? The function `buildCodemap` can return any type, as long as it has an instance of `Bit`. So what type should it be?

The compiler doesn't know. There is nowhere to glean this information from. It's ambiguous.

And this is exactly what the compiler is telling you: "*ambiguous type variable*".

One way to fix this is to provide a type annotation (exactly as the error message says, by the way):

```
let codeMaphTest :: Codemap Int = buildCodemap treeTest
```

Note that I chose `Int` just as an example, because I don't know which type you meant (I'm somewhat like the compiler in that respect). Please substitute your own type - the one you actually wanted there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is indeed ambiguous. `buildCodemap treeTest` has a polymorphic type `Bits a => Codemap a`, so it can be used as a `Codemap Int`, a `Codemap Bool`, or even as another type if you defines further instances of `Bits`.

This is not a problem, on its own, but later on you try to use this value (e.g., to print it), so we really need to pick a concrete type `a`.

You could pick `a` at the definition point:

```
let codeMaphTest :: Codemap Int
    codeMaphTest = buildCodemap treeTest
```

Or, alternatively, you could choose `a` later on, where you use it

```
print (codeMaphTest :: Codemap Int)
```